# Is it possible to transform log messages by using a script?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I want to transform the log messages, replace the author name which in my case is just an alphanumeric code by the real name which I will retrieve from a local file. Is there a way to do this with TortoiseSVN, e.g. by running a script?

If Tortoise was calling the command line SVN I could just call a batch file instead and transform the output before passing it back to Tortoise.

Comment: Is it acceptable to overwrite commits author  in svn?

Comment: @uzsolt Not in the commit per se, only in what is displayed to the user in the log messages. I.e. instead of  "author:TZ7885" I would rather have "author:KnuthD"

Comment: Understand. I don't use tortoisesvn so I have no idea :(